# CakePHP, How to populate a select box from a sql database

Tags: php, cakephp

In my controller I have this field

```
$employee = TableRegistry::get('employees');
$allNames = $employee->find()->extract('employee_name');
$this->set('name', $allNames);
```

Works fine, retrieves the data I want then in my template

i have the code which belongs to a form that im trying to submit and save to a database.

```
<?= $this->Form->select('employee', $name, ['escape' => false])?>
```

Which works fine except when I submit it comes back saying it wasnt able to save to the database.

I suspect its this because if i change the input to something id just type in it saves fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `$query = $articles->find('list');`

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

Chapter :Finding Key/Value Pairs¶